# HTTPResponse object has no attribute json

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, httpresponse

I am retrieving data from an API which outputs some json content. However when I try to store the data into a simple text file with the following code:

```
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'http://my/endpoint/url'
myheaders = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
mydata = {'username':'***','password':'***'}
response  =  http.request('POST', url, body=json.dumps(mydata).encode('UTF-8'), headers=myheaders)
print(response.status_code)
data = response.json()

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

I get the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'json'
```

So, I also tried using response.text with the following code:

```
file = open('data.json', 'w')
file.write(response.text)
file.close()
```

But I also get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Why can't I store my response into a simple text file ?

Comment: if you would use module `requests` then you would have `.json()` and `.text` but I don't know if module `urllib3` works in the same way. Maybe find documentation for module `urllib3`. Maybe it has different name like `.content` or `.body` and you have to manually use `decode()` and `json.loads()`

Comment: Did you try storing response directly, instead of response.json() or response.text?

Comment: BTW: I think you mix code for module `requests` with code for module `urllib3`. You use `response.status_code` but it gives me error because `urllib3` has `status`, not `status_code`. But module `reuqests` has `status_code`

Comment: To people coming here because they were annotating code with `django.http.response.HttpResponse`: Use `django.http.response.JsonResponse`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you mix code for module `requests` with code for module `urllib3`

`requests` has `status_code`. `.text`, `.content`, `.json()` but `urllib3` doesn't have it

**requests**

```
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'

mydata = {'username': '***', 'password': '***'}

response = requests.post(url, json=mydata)
print(response.status_code)

data = response.json()
print(data)

with open('data.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    #json.dump(data, f)
```

**urllib3**

```
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
myheaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
mydata = {'username': '***', 'password': '***'}

response = http.request('POST', url, body=json.dumps(mydata).encode('UTF-8'), headers=myheaders)
#print(dir(response))
print(response.status)

data = json.loads(response.data)
print(data)

with open('data.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `HTTPResponse` object in urllib3 v2.0 [is going to have](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/commit/c5bc7163022c0ac2e765cdb7309937a53e32d368) a `.json()` method. The [latest documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#json-content) is already advertising this method but it's not released [on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/#history) yet.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has the same problem as me:
I got such error (`HTTPResponse object has no attribute json`) when trying to run my code, which contained `urllib3` `HTTPResponse.json()` method, in AWS Lambda. It was running fine locally.

I wanted to avoid bundling, so I wanted to use library that is contained in AWS Lambda runtimes. Hence `urllib3`. It used to include `requests` library but it got removed in Python 3.8 runtime and later. See entry on [AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/).

Anyway apparently the `urllib3` version included in Python 3.12 runtime is some older one. I also asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77626894/3284243) on how to check the actual dependencies that are included in the runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Mihau, many thanks for this input. I was going crazy with that ! I assume we have to go with the json.loads method.