# Find out python modules with versions that are included in given aws python lambda runtime

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When trying to run my code, which contained `urllib3` `HTTPResponse.json()` method, in AWS Lambda, Python 3.12 runtime, I got an error `HTTPResponse object has no attribute json`.
It was running fine locally.
After I changed `response.json()` to `json.loads(response.data)` it started working.

I wanted to avoid bundling, so I wanted to use library that is contained in AWS Lambda runtimes. Apparently the urllib3 version included in Python 3.12 runtime is some older one.

Is there a way to tell which modules in which versions are contained in given python lambda runtime?

I've found a list and a tool [here](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3), which probably can give me an answer after some work, but I wonder if there's any 'ready-made' resource?

Comment: That gist is the best resource that I'm aware of. You could potentially automate your own solution based on it e.g. deploy and run it on each supported Python runtime once a month and export the results to a JSON file in S3 that you can then retrieve programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The way Lambda works is to run your code, you can include your environment folder into your Lambda build if you want (not recommended) another way is using Lambda layers, it's strongly recommended.

Normal you can find others out there you can use lambda layers from if you don't know how to build lambda layers or want to, but if you pick a lambda layer outside remember you assign the trust of the code you execute with your lambda code.

You can read more about how to work with Lambda layers here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html

Comment: I know that layering is the recommended approach for dependencies, but I wanted to avoid it since my lambda is really tiny, and I'm striving to have it build quickly, and adding layers seemed to slow the build process down considerably.

Comment: Then you need to pip install that package into a folder and importer from there, its a wirdt way to use Lamda on, a better way can be to build it to a container and then ship the container as Lambda function then you don't need layers, that how i normally do becures the layer can be a pain, Docker containers are slower but much easier to debug and deploy so i will go for layers or container build to ecr